# PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR on node.js server using mysql DB running on Ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a server on **AWS EC2** instance on ubuntu using **node.js** and **MYSQL**.It was working fine for 3 days, **suddenly it stopped working**.

On Googling i found that was due to lost connection in MYSQL DB. But could not find the exact cause of the fatal.

I am using following code for MYSQL connection

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD
 });

connection.query('USE MY_DB');
```

And for querying like this

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM movie', function(err, rows){
 var users = {"users" : rows};
 res.send(users);

  });
  });
```

And log for the fatal:

```
2017-01-20T00:22:23.721Z - [31merror[39m: GET /users  : Error: ER_SERVER_SHUTDOWN: Server shutdown in progress
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
at Connection.query (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)
at /home/ubuntu/myserver/myserver.js:125:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

one more log:

```
2017-01-20T00:22:24.189Z - [31merror[39m: deleteRecords  : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
at Connection._implyConnect (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:467:10)
at Connection.query (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:212:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/myserver/myserver.js:21:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-01-20T00:22:28.135Z - [31merror[39m: GET /users  : Error: Cannot      enqueue Query after fatal error.
at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:199:16)
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:13)
at Connection.query (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)
at /home/ubuntu/myserver/myserver.js:125:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/myserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

I want to know the exact issue and the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pretty straightforward, really... `ER_SERVER_SHUTDOWN: Server shutdown in progress` ... the MySQL Service was stopping. Next, `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` the MySQL Service isn't running.  Check the logs?

Comment: Yes you are right, I can see the log. But i want to know what makes server getting shutdown.